# Potential WebApi Bug Overriding routes create multiple Endpoints

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api, controller, routes

I think I've discovered a webapi bug.

This is a simplified version of the problem I have this Controller, whose routes get list is suppose to link up to the employeeId

```
[RoutePrefix("/divisions/{parentId}/employees/{employeeId}/dependent")]
public class EmployeeDependentController : ParentBasedListController<EmployeeDependentDTO, GlobalEntityKey<IEmployee>>
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ReadRoute("")]
    public override EmployeeDependentDTO[] GetList(GlobalEntityKey<IEmployee> employeeId, bool keysOnly = false)
    {
        return base.GetList(employeeId, keysOnly);
    }

    protected override EmployeeDependentDTO[] GetListImp(GlobalEntityKey<IEmployee> employeeKey)
    {
        return GlobalFactory<IEmployeeDependentService>.Instance.GetList(employeeKey);
    }
}
```

However it's inheriting from a base class whose parameter name links up to the parentId normally

```
 public abstract class ParentBasedListController<TEntityDTOHeader, TEntityDTOKey, TParentEntityKey> : ApiController
    where TParentEntityKey : IKey
    where TEntityDTOHeader : TEntityDTOKey
{
    #region Public Methods

    [HttpGet]
    [ReadRoute("")]
    public virtual TEntityDTOKey[] GetList(TParentEntityKey parentId, bool keysOnly = false)
    {
        if (false == keysOnly)
        {
            return this.GetListImp(parentId).Cast<TEntityDTOKey>().ToArray();
        }
        return this.GetKeyListImp(parentId);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Protected Methods

    protected abstract TEntityDTOHeader[] GetListImp(TParentEntityKey parentKey);

    #endregion
}
```

When I Override the get list method, webapi  returns an error for duplicate matching actions.   What's even more interesting is that i've tried this with the new keyword which should hide that method in both case I receive this error.

Why is this happening? is this a bug in webapi?, I understand that they are using reflection for the controllers but they should be able to determine if a method was overridden and use the correct one.

I have several controllers tied to this route and several controller inheriting from this base class both in which would be a hassle to change, What is the best work around for this?

Comment: Check this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36012524/web-api-2-2-inherited-controller-with-route-overrides-is-this-possible

Comment: Remove the attributes on the inherited action of the `EmployeeDependentController ` as they match those from the inherited class. In **attribute routing** the framework is looking at the **attributes** which you have duplicated.

Comment: @Nkosi that's I'll investigate that when I get back